# How to send a variable from ASP.Net to an IP address using TCP

Tags: .net, asp.net, variables, tcp, ip

I am developing a web for my project. I am new to Asp.net and to this forum.
my project is control a led from website.

I am using network module to connect my microcontroler with web server.
what i want to do is send variable from ASP.net to network module IP address.

I am very thanks to everyone who can help me 
here is ASP code (page.aspx.cs).

```
    public partial class VirtualRemote : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        // when this button is click i want to send a variable example "A"
          to network module IP example 192.168.1.2. so network module can pass the
          variable to microC , i already have microC program to receive from network  module  


        }

}
```

Comment: what protcol type tcp or udp?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Socket` instance in your `Button1_Click` method and send what you need to send to your network aware microcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), PORT_NUMBER));

// Send the file name.
var A = "TEST STRING";
clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(A));
```

More about [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class